# Limpiar y buscar datos de comunicación serial en Python

Tags: python

Tengo una comunicación serial entre Arduino y Python. Los datos llegan con este formato:

```
b' Gyro_Xraw -53.00 Gyro_Yraw 26.00 Gyro_Zraw -6.00\r\n'
b' Gyro_Xnorm -3.11 Gyro_Ynorm 1.52 Gyro_Znorm -0.37\r\n'
b' Accel_Xraw 2816.00 Accel_Yraw 9644.00 Accel_Zraw 11360.00\r\n'
b' Accel_Xnorm 1.63 Accel_Ynorm 5.80 Accel_Znorm 6.83\r\n'
b' Temp_C 33.24 Gyro_Xraw -45.00 Gyro_Yraw 26.00 Gyro_Zraw -9.00\r\n'
b' Gyro_Xnorm -2.68 Gyro_Ynorm 1.52 Gyro_Znorm -0.49\r\n'
```

Me gustaría tener los datos mas limpio, sacar los valores de todos ellos para tenerlos en variable, por ejemplo:

```
Gyro_Xraw = -53.00
yro_Yraw = 26.00 
Gyro_Zraw = -6.00
Gyro_Xnorm = 3.11
```

El código en Python es:

```
import serial
import time

print("Loading")
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 115200, timeout=0)
time.sleep(1)

while True:
    data = str(ser.readline())
    print(data)
```

Comment: Y, ¿cuál es tu pregunta o qué problema tienes para lograrlo?

Comment: No se cual es la mejor forma para limpiar los datos, me recomeindas hacer algo? Necesito ayuda con eso. Soy nuevo con Python.

Comment: Si estás aprendiendo, no te centres en _la mejor forma_, investiga para encontrar alguna, empieza, y si te trabas en el camino, entonces preguntas y aquí alguien te echará un cable.

Answer (score 0):

en una lista por ejemplo ,  podrías obtener los elementos en forma de columna de esta forma. esto te puede ayudar sólo como idea de ordenamiento porque no sé cómo arduino maneja o muestra sus datos.

```
element = [ 'Gyro_Xraw  -53.00' , 'Gyro_Yraw  26.00' , 'Gyro_Zraw  -6.00' ,  
            'Gyro_Xnorm  -3.11' ,  'Gyro_Ynorm 1.52' , ' Gyro_Znorm -0.37' ,
            'Accel_Xraw 2816.00' ,' Accel_Yraw 9644.00' , ' Accel_Zraw 11360.00' ]                 
                  
for a in (element) :
    print()
    print (a)
```